# Is it possible to depend on a specific sub project in qmake?

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

Suppose I have one big project `Example` with two subprojects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. `ProjectB`, at the same time, has two subprojects, `ProjectB1` and `ProjectB2`. Is it possible to specify that `ProjectA` depends of one of `ProjectB`'s subprojects?

**projectA.pro**

```
TEMPLATE=app
...
```

**projectB.pro**

```
TEMPLATE=subdirs
SUBDIRS+= projectB1 projectB2
projectB1.file = projectB1.pro
projectB2.file = projectB2.pro
```

**Example.pro**

```
TEMPLATE  = subdirs
SUBDIRS +=  projectA projectB 
projectA.file    = projectA.pro
projectA.depends = projectB.projectB1  (?)
projectB.file = projectB.pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by explicitly specifying `projectB1`. Add this to the end of `Example.pro`:

```
projectB1.file = projectB1.pro
projectA.depends = projectB1
SUBDIRS += projectB1
```